# Can enum as singleton extend a class

Tags: java, enums, singleton

I want to implement a Singleton class using enum. But the problem is I also want to extend a BaseClass. Is there a way where I can implement this?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/179386/what-are-the-downsides-of-implementing-a-singleton-with-javas-enum

Comment: Short answer: no.  Long answer: nooooo.  Enums cannot extend another class.